# Retrieving data from CouchDB and yii?

Tags: json, yii, couchdb, cloudant

If we make any changes in the CouchDB JSON document, which part do we need to load? Do we load the whole document or just the corresponding array?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's really hard to understand what you're looking for.

Comment: @Ofir Baruch if i updating data, need to retrieve the previous datas and appending in that.So while made any changes,retrieve the full document with id and revision number or retrieve only appendable array

Answer (score 0):

You can make some in place updates using [Update handlers](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html#update-functions). Other than that, from a "client" there's no support for individual field updates, hence what you `PUT` back in is seen as the "current" document.